# SwingUtilities.invokeLater, SwingWorker and gif icon animation issue

Tags: java, user-interface, animated-gif, swingworker, swingutilities

I am trying to load a gif icon, while i am doing some expensive work in background. But issue is this, gif(animation) icon is not loading.

If i replace gif icon with png, it works fine.

Here is Test class code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    panel.add(loginButton);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL urlProcessing = Test.class.getResource("processing.gif");
            //URL urlProcessing = Test.class.getResource("processing.png");
            ImageIcon processingIcon = new ImageIcon(urlProcessing);
            loginButton.setText("Authenticating...");
            loginButton.setIcon(processingIcon);
            loginButton.revalidate();
            loginButton.repaint();


            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {     

                    Worker worker = new Worker(frame);
                    try {
                        worker.doInBackground();                            
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
}
```

When user click login button, i change the text of button and put gif icon on it. In

> SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

method i start background expensive task through SwingWorker Thread. Right now, no need publish and process methods of SwingWorker class, because i am not doing any work during background expensive task.

If i remove "SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {" method and call directly SwingWorker class, then both gif and png icons not working(displaying on button).

I tried simple thread to change text and set icon on button, but it did not worked as well.

Here is SwingWorker class code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Worker extends SwingWorker<String, String> implements Runnable {

private JFrame testFrame;
// some public and private properties

public Worker(JFrame frame){
    // doing some assignments

    this.testFrame = frame;
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.done();
    System.out.println("Done method called");
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    String chunks = null;
    publish(chunks);
    // Doing some very expensive work, HTTP request, DB operations etc...
    while (i < 10) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Value of i: "+i);
        i++;
    }
    this.done();
    testFrame.setVisible(false);
    return null;
}
}
```

Any Idea? what happening in GUI main thread? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `doInBackground` directly, you should call `execute` instead. Also you should be able to make that call in the UI thread (i.e. no need to call it inside an `invokeLater`). In your `doInBackground` implementation, you should do changes to the UI in the UI thread (i.e. `invokeLater` should be used there).

Comment: Good luck with it all :)